# Strange behavior with WHERE NOT regular expression

Tags: php, mysql, regex, json

I'm experience a problem with the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `anytable` WHERE NOT (anyColumn regexp '.smf.')
```

I have 656 rows in total. I'm getting an empty result using `WHERE` (without the `NOT`), but with the `NOT` I'm only getting back 40 results, not the entire 656 results...

In another column (where there are some positive results) it's working with 7 found and 649 not found.

#### Appendix

I'm storing `json_encode` PHP associative arrays in the MySQL database. Example from the Database (JSON encoded):

```
[{"#identifier#":"test","#status#":"123","#anyColumn#":"123","#id#":"507"}]
```

#### SOLUTION

I had empty rows in my Database, that were NULL. MYSQL has Problems with that so i changed the fields to be empty but not Null :)

Comment: could you provide example on http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found by OP:

> I had empty rows in my Database, that were NULL. MYSQL has Problems with that so i changed the fields to be empty but not Null :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine if you changed the query to:

`SELECT * FROM anytable WHERE NOT (anyColumn regexp '.smf.' OR anyColumn IS NULL)`